# How do I show data from another worksheet in my listbox?

Tags: excel, vba

I've tried using the `lstDisplay1.RowSource = wb.Worksheet("Database").Range("A1:B5000")` but it doesn't work.

```
Private Sub brandadd_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim AddNew As Range
Set AddNew = Worksheets("Database").Range("A5000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

AddNew.Offset(0, 0).Value = brandcode.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 1).Value = brandname.Text

MsgBox ("Data added sucessfully!")

lstDisplay1.ColumnCount = 2
lstDisplay1.RowSource = ("A1:B5000")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**Change:**

```
lstDisplay1.RowSource = wb.Worksheet("Database").Range("A1:B5000")
```

**Use:**

```
lstDisplay1.RowSource = "Database!A1:B5000"
```

Answer From: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52366579/how-to-set-listbox1-rowsource-property)

---

**Modified Code:**

```
Private Sub brandadd_Click()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim AddNew As Range
Set AddNew = Worksheets("Database").Range("A5000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

AddNew.Offset(0, 0).Value = brandcode.Text
AddNew.Offset(0, 1).Value = brandname.Text

MsgBox ("Data added sucessfully!")

lstDisplay1.ColumnCount = 2
lstDisplay1.RowSource = "Database!A1:B" & Worksheets("Database").Range("A5000").End(xlUp).Row

End Sub
```

Comment: How can I improve this code? How can I make the listbox show only all the inputted data? Not all the cells A1 up to B5000.

Comment: What do you mean by Inputted Data  ? Try the modified Code

Comment: I have data from cells A1 up to B475 and once I add a new data the listbox will show the data from cells A1 up to B476, so on and so forth.

Comment: Try the Modified Code. It will do it for you.

Comment: There's an error "Could not set the RowSource property. Invalid property value."

Comment: It's working in my system like that. Check the Spellings again.